# Input numeric to proceed to next line but exception when entering a non numeric

Tags: java, if-statement, input, int, numeric

I am new to programming and am still wrapping my head around things.

So pretty much, I am trying to add a line that will allow entering, for example, a text "ABC", and for it not to produce an exception but rather request for a numeric value be entered "123".

As i said i am new to programming and I have tried many attempts, but i think because im using "int age = input.nextInt();" it stops me entering text in the if statement. Im not really sure.

This is for an assignment as well. Let me know if you need to know anything more. I do want to learn, though i also dont know what to look at. etc.

```
   System.out.println("Please enter your age:");

   String bracket= "";

   int age = input.nextInt();

   if (age <= 20){
     bracket = "20 & under";
   }
   if (age > 20 && age <= 35){
     bracket = "21-35";
   }
   if (age > 35 && age <= 70){
     bracket = "36-70";
   }
   if (age > 70){
     bracket = "71 & over";
   }
```

Comment: Maybe read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop, you need to check if your `Scanner` has an `int` before you try to read it, and you can simplify your `if` chain with some `else`(s). Like,

```
String bracket = "";
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your age:");
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        int age = input.nextInt();
        if (age < 20) {
            bracket = "20 & under";
        } else if (age < 36) {
            bracket = "21-35";
        } else if (age < 71) {
            bracket = "36-70";
        } else {
            bracket = "71 & over";
        }
        break;
    } else {
        input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried and this worked well. Do you mind sparing more time and just explain why please?

Comment: @wallace Why what? You need to check that the `Scanner` has an `int` (`if (input.hasNextInt())`) if it does, then `age = input.nextInt();` otherwise, consume the input that is **not** an `int` with `input.nextLine();`

Comment: I understand. Thanks.

Comment: @wallace You're very welcome and welcome to StackOverflow. Don't forget to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I have a quick concern with the code and not sure how to resolve it. When entering an initial input that doesn't meet the conditions and repeats the request for an age that is numeric, it does so twice, just in this instance, and every other input that is incorrect is just the single sentence. Do you know why this might be? Thank you!